# Crystal: how to implement multiple abstract methods with one method in child?

Tags: inheritance, abstract, crystal-lang

Suppose I have an abstract struct that needs to operate on two kinds of inputs like so (for more context, see [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059132/crystal-how-to-require-implementing-class-operate-on-self-instead-of-all-siblin?noredirect=1#comment98774094_56059132)).

```
abstract struct Numberlike
  alias Num = (Int32 | Float64)
  abstract def -
  abstract def -(other : self)
  abstract def -(other : Num)
end
```

If my implementation can use `self` and `Num` interchangeably, it seems reasonable to just put them together:

```
struct Term < Numberlike
  alias Num = (Int32 | Float64)
  getter coeff : Num
  getter sym : Symbol

  def initialize(@coeff, @sym); end

  def -(other : self | Num)
    self.class.new(coeff - other, sym)
  end

  def -
    self.class.new(-coeff, sym)
  end
end
```

The truth is though that since the type is `self | Num` it matches neither the `self` nor the `Num` requirement of the abstract class.

You can see for yourself in [this playground](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6vyv).

Is there a way to combine these like I want? I'd rather not duplicate the code unnecessarily (i.e. the following compiles but I don't like it):

```
struct Term < Numberlike
  alias Num = (Int32 | Float64)
  getter coeff : Num
  getter sym : Symbol

  def initialize(@coeff, @sym); end

  def -(other : self)
    self.class.new(coeff - other, sym)
  end

  def -(other : Num)
    self.class.new(coeff - other, sym)
  end

  def -
    self.class.new(-coeff, sym)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've been able to come up with, is to define the joined method in the abstract class, somewhat similar to what Samual is talking about. If done this way, the implementing structs are free to define each separately or all combined.

```
abstract struct Addable
  abstract def +(other : self)
  abstract def +(other : Int32)
  def +(other : self | Int32)
    if other.is_a?(Int32) ? self + other : self + other
  end
end
```

The way this works is that if they are defined separately by you, then the combined method comes along for type safety but isn't used. If you define them together, you override the third method, but the other two won't give you trouble because a program which satisfies the third condition satisfies the first two.

Here's a demonstration: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6y3j

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a simple solve, but is probably not as clean as just separating the two methods. [play](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6vzp) You just needed to change the abstract method to be a tuple instead of two separate methods.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, I actually do want the implementing classes to handle both types. If their internals require them to do so separately, I don't want my abstract to *prevent* that. See in [this playground](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6vzq) my subclass will use two implementations but now it can't.

Comment: Okay, I think I have found the way to do [this](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6w86). Define the `#-(other : self | Num)` in the abstract class that makes use of `#-(other : self)` and `#-(other : Num)`. This shouldn't compile unless the two methods are defined. If you want to define both together, just define `#-(other : self | Num)` in the child class.

Comment: I like the idea, but it assumes we know ahead of time how the two should be combined. For subtraction, thanks to the requirement of an addition and negation operator, this is actually a reasonable thing to do. Thanks for pointing it out!

But it doesn't solve the core problem, i.e., this won't work for addition where in general we can't expect that both Num and self can definitely share the logic. Right? Or am I missing something?